# Android widget start activity when imageview is clicked

Tags: android, logging, widget, android-activity

I am developing an analog clock widget for andriod I have an imageview in the widget, i need to add a click listener to it so when it is clicked it will start an activity (facebook share activity) here is the  code

```
public class Widget extends AppWidgetProvider
{    
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    { 
        super.onReceive(context, intent);
        PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
        Intent alarmClockIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN).addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
        Log.d("ARH","CLICKK");
        String clockImpls[][] = {
                {"HTC Alarm Clock", "com.htc.android.worldclock", "com.htc.android.worldclock.WorldClockTabControl" },
                {"Standar Alarm Clock", "com.android.deskclock", "com.android.deskclock.AlarmClock"},
                {"Froyo Nexus Alarm Clock", "com.google.android.deskclock", "com.android.deskclock.DeskClock"},
                {"Moto Blur Alarm Clock", "com.motorola.blur.alarmclock",  "com.motorola.blur.alarmclock.AlarmClock"},
                {"Samsung Galaxy Clock", "com.sec.android.app.clockpackage","com.sec.android.app.clockpackage.ClockPackage"}
        };

        boolean foundClockImpl = false;

        for(int i=0; i<clockImpls.length; i++) {
            String vendor = clockImpls[i][0];
            String packageName = clockImpls[i][1];
            String className = clockImpls[i][2];
            try {
                ComponentName cn = new ComponentName(packageName, className);
                ActivityInfo aInfo = packageManager.getActivityInfo(cn, PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
                alarmClockIntent.setComponent(cn);   
                foundClockImpl = true;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(vendor + " does not exists");
            }
        }

        if (foundClockImpl) {
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, alarmClockIntent, 0);
            String action = intent.getAction();
            Log.v("info",action);
            if (AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE.equals(action))
            {

                RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget);


                Intent fbook = new Intent(context,FacebookShare.class);
                PendingIntent fbookPIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, fbook, 0);  

                views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.facebooksharebtn, fbookPIntent); 
                AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context).updateAppWidget(intent.getIntArrayExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS), views);
            }else{ 
            }
        }

    }





}
```

and the Activity which needs to appear is

```
public class FacebookShare extends Activity {


    Facebook facebook = new Facebook("304105172993733");  
    boolean isLoggedIn = false;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.facebook);

        facebook.authorize(this, new String[]{"publish_stream"}, new DialogListener(){

            public void onComplete(Bundle values) {

                Log.d("COMPLETE","AUTH COMPLETE. VALUES: "+values.size());
                Log.d("AUTH TOKEN","== "+values.getString(Facebook.TOKEN));
                updateStatus(values.getString(Facebook.TOKEN));
            }

            public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e) {
                Log.d("FACEBOOK ERROR","FB ERROR. MSG: "+e.getMessage()+", CAUSE: "+e.getCause());
            }

            public void onError(DialogError e) {
                Log.e("ERROR","AUTH ERROR. MSG: "+e.getMessage()+", CAUSE: "+e.getCause());
            }

            public void onCancel() {
                Log.d("CANCELLED","AUTH CANCELLED");
            }
        });
    }

    public void updateStatus(String accessToken){
        try {
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("message", "test update");  
            bundle.putString(Facebook.TOKEN,accessToken); 
            String response = facebook.request("me/feed",bundle,"POST");
            Log.d("UPDATE RESPONSE",""+response);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            Log.e("MALFORMED URL",""+e.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("IOEX",""+e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        Log.d("onActivityResult","onActivityResult");
        facebook.authorizeCallback(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

}
```

both are in same package

here is the exception that I get when I click on the imageview

> E/AndroidRuntime(1130): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start
>   activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.mnet.rockwell.widgets.AnalogClock/com.mnet.widgets.AnalogClock.FacebookShare}:
>   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #31: Error
>   inflating class android.widget.FrameLayout

also this I dont get any logs on logcat

here is what I have tried for log

```
 Log.d("ARH","CLICKK");
Log.e("ARH","CLICKK");
Log.v("ARH","CLICKK");
Log.i("ARH","CLICKK");
```

I am new to Android development but I am a Java developer, please any suggestions

here is facebook.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Thank You For Sharing Rockwell Widget" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginRight="27dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:text="   Close   " />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: The exception suggests that something is wrong with the XML that you are inflating. Likely it will be the R.layout.facebook one... Can you attach it to your post?

Comment: thanks for your reply patrick i have just attached the xml file thanks again

Comment: Can you perhaps state whether your widget launches/installs on the home screen at all or fails right then? I tried out the parts of your code (that you provided), and I do get output from the widget (the '...clock does not exist') and also get the 'ARH'-'CLICKK' debug message... If you do not get that far - have you correctly entered all the necessary data in your android Manifest file and set them to the right values?

Comment: You have supplied the wrong layout file. The error refers to a `FrameLayout`; the file you have here does not contain a `FrameLayout`.

Comment: It properly installs and clock works properly it just another activity which does not start on click of an image view, basically that image is a facebook Icon that i want to use to start facebookshare activity